# Trying to read data with experimental feature from chrome (serial port) but code freeze on await data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, serial-port

I'm trying to use serial port, experimental feature from google chrome with reactjs. I do the connection with a digital balance (https://www.toledobrasil.com/blob/products/5_image1566803343.jpg) but the function freeze when wait for any data.

```
await port.open({
      baudRate: 9600,
      dataBits: 7,
      stopBits: 1,
      parity: "none",
    });
const _reader = port.readable.getReader();
while (true) {
      const { value, done } = await _reader.read(); //the execution freeze here
      console.log({ value, done }); //this line never is executed because the await above never return
    }
```

Comment: are you sure it's freezing and not throwing an error? add a try/catch around that await to perform some basic error checking

Comment: Without wrapping it in a while loop, what is the logged result of `await _reader.read();`?